# Google Calendar API Refresh accessToken

Tags: php, laravel, api, calendar

I'm running into an issue with Google Calendar API.

I can login with google via authCallback but after one hour it gives me a Invalid Credentials error

**App\Http\Controllers\gCalendarController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Calendar;
use Google_Service_Calendar_Event;
use Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class gCalendarController extends Controller
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

        $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
        $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);

            $calendarId = 'primary';

            $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId);
            $test = $_SESSION['access_token'];
            return view('calendar.tyfuscalender', compact('result', 'test'));

        } else {
            return redirect()->route('oauthCallback');
        }
    }

    public function oauth()
    {   
        session_start();

        $rurl = action('gCalendarController@oauth');
        $this->client->setRedirectUri($rurl);
        if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
            $filtered_url = filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            return redirect($filtered_url);
        } else {
            $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();
            return redirect()->route('cal.index');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('calendar.createEvent');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        session_start();
        $startDateTime = $request->start_date;
        $endDateTime = $request->end_date;

        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);

            $calendarId = 'primary';
            $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event([
                'summary' => $request->title,
                'description' => $request->description,
                'start' => ['dateTime' => $startDateTime],
                'end' => ['dateTime' => $endDateTime],
                'reminders' => ['useDefault' => true],
            ]);
            $results = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
            if (!$results) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong']);
            }
            return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Event Created']);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('oauthCallback');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param $eventId
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @internal param int $id
     */
    public function show($eventId)
    {
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

            $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);
            $event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);

            if (!$event) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong']);
            }
            return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $event]);

        } else {
            return redirect()->route('oauthCallback');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param $eventId
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @internal param int $id
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $eventId)
    {
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);

            $startDateTime = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->toRfc3339String();

            $eventDuration = 30; //minutes

            if ($request->has('end_date')) {
                $endDateTime = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->toRfc3339String();

            } else {
                $endDateTime = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->addMinutes($eventDuration)->toRfc3339String();
            }

            // retrieve the event from the API.
            $event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);

            $event->setSummary($request->title);

           $event->setDescription($request->description);

            //start time
            $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
            $start->setDateTime($startDateTime);
            $event->setStart($start);

            //end time
            $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
            $end->setDateTime($endDateTime);
            $event->setEnd($end);

            $updatedEvent = $service->events->update('primary', $event->getId(), $event);


            if (!$updatedEvent) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong']);
            }
            return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $updatedEvent]);

        } else {
            return redirect()->route('oauthCallback');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param $eventId
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @internal param int $id
     */
    public function destroy($eventId)
    {
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);
            $service->events->delete('primary', $eventId);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('oauthCallback');
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error message

```
Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 118:
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "authError",
"message": "Invalid Credentials",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
}
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Invalid Credentials"
}
}
```

I'm thinking it's something with the token that expires, but i have no idea on how to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if i go back to the '/oauth' route, it prompts me to allow google use my google account again.. Instead of refreshing my accesstoken.. Is there a way to make it refresh? without going back to '/oauth'..

Thanks